# getIndexDDLStatements only applies for value columns?

Tags: cassandra, ignite

```
    public List<String> getIndexDDLStatements(String table) {
        List<String> idxDDLs = new LinkedList<>();

        Set<String> keyCols = new HashSet<>(keyPersistenceSettings.getTableColumns());

        List<PojoValueField> fields = valPersistenceSettings.getFields();

        for (PojoField field : fields) {
            if (!keyCols.contains(field.getColumn()) && ((PojoValueField)field).isIndexed())
                idxDDLs.add(((PojoValueField)field).getIndexDDL(keyspace, table));
        }

        return idxDDLs;
    }
```

I got a table with columns like "keyPersistence setting column: Id, key, item" and valuePersistence: value". According to api provided by org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence KeyValuePersistenceSettings (as shown in code block). It's only applied for creating secondary index on value columns?

My table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE liquid.c_liquid_mlog_mlog_trade_slices (
    id int,
    key text,
    item text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, key, item))
```

And I can manually create secondary index on 'id'. But obviously I cannot use getIndexDDLStatements to create secondary index on 'id' because 'id' is an column in 'keyPersistenceSettings'?